# installing php documentation locally with user notes

Tags: php, documentation, osx-snow-leopard, mamp, chm

I often want to lookup php documentation when I do not have internet access. I've installed the php docs on my local server using these instructions:
https://wiki.php.net/doc/articles/localdocsetup

I see the php documentation has a chm version that includes user notes but I find no docs on how to use them. Apparently chm is a windows only format. There are OS X chm readers but I'd like to have the User Contributed Notes appear at the bottom of each page just like they do at php.net. I'm using Snow Leopard on the Mac with MAMP.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,
TD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Chmox](http://chmox.sourceforge.net/)? Their screenshot shows the PHP manual as well. It seems to work on my mid-2011 MBP running 10.7.5.

Comment: Does Chmox now really support joining multiple CHM files? Last time i checked it did not work and this is all the user ask about.